# Add hyperlink into Word Content Control with VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a Word 2010 template. When used, a form is presented to the user and they are prompted to enter a string in a textbox named *BugNumTextBox*. Upon command, I wish to construct a URL, create a hyperlink, and insert that into the document.

The desired insertion point (anchor) is a Rich Text Content Control with a tag name of "foo".
For the *address* parameter I have attempted:

1) To specify the range of the content control
2) To specify the range of a bookmark (named BugNum) that I created inside of the content control.

Neither have worked, resulting in run-time errors.
Can anyone suggest a method to achieve this?
Below is a non-working example of method 2 above.

```
ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Bookmark("BugNum").Range, Address:= _
"http://bugs.fubar.net/show_bug.cgi?id=" & BugNumTextBox, _
SubAddress:="", ScreenTip:="", TextToDisplay:=""
```

Thank you much.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you access the *ContentControls Object Collection* instead.
Something like:

```
Dim ccRtxt As ContentControl

Set ccRtxt = ActiveDocument.ContentControls(1)
ccRtxt.Range.Hyperlinks.Add ccRtxt.Range, _
    "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26538906/" & _
    "add-hyperlink-into-word-content-control-with-vba"
```

Above will work on the scenario you describe where you only have 1 *ContentControl*.
If you have many such objects, you can do this:

```
Dim ccRtxt As ContentControl

For Each ccRtxt In ActiveDocument.ContentControls
    If ccRtxt.Tag = "foo" Then
        ccRtxt.Range.Hyperlinks.Add ccRtxt.Range, _
            "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26538906/" & _
            "add-hyperlink-into-word-content-control-with-vba"
    End If
Next
```

This adds this question as hyperlink address in your *Rich Text Content Control*.
You can adjust the address property to suit your needs. HTH.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I have implemented using the method of direct contentcontrol object as you describe. It results in a similar error to another idea I had.

The debug highlights the following:
    ccRtxt.Range.Hyperlinks.Add ccRtxt.Range, _
    "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26538906/" & _
    "add-hyperlink-into-word-content-control-with-vba"
and gives an error of:
    Run-time error '4103'
    Out of memory

Any ideas?

Comment: @scorf Re-start Excel or change the http address and try another address. I tried and tested that code and it works fine at my end provided you have the correct objects.

Comment: Thanks again L42. I'm trying to do this in Word 2010. I tried to replicate it in excel, but I have not been able to figure out how to add a rich text content control in excel as of yet.

Comment: @scorf Yep, I work on Word 2010 as well. And it runs fine. I uploaded my test file [in this link](http://wikisend.com/download/264626/adding)

Comment: OK, so it turns out that there is some other unknown interaction that is actually causing the error. I rebuilt my template from scratch and the method you propose works like a charm. Thanks again for your help and patience @L42 !