# Inserting Hyperlink into Content Control in Word - Have tried several ways but no success

Tags: vba, ms-word

Can anyone help on this please.

I have a word userform that populates a letter. Depending on the optionbutton pressed I want to insert a hyperlink that I have typed into the Macro VBA editor. I can get it to work by using the line below but the link is not clickable. I have tried playing about with the `HYPERLINKS.ADD` function without success. So My questions is, if my content control is called "Link" (also the TAG) how do I add text and make it a clickable hyperlink all in one?

```
Set CClist = ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("Link")
  For Each cc In CClist
    cc.Range.Text = "MY LINK"
  Next cc
```

I have tried:

```
Set CClist = ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("date")
  For Each cc In CClist
    cc.Range.hyperlinks.add range ("my link")
  Next cc
```

Damian

Comment: Is there an excel issue here? if not don't tag it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26538906/add-hyperlink-into-word-content-control-with-vba

Comment: Your questions sounds like you're trying to insert a hyperlink in a content control that links back to the containing content control. Please clarify. Have you tried using the macro recorder to get the correct syntax?

Answer (score 1):

Try something along the lines of:

```
With ActiveDocument
  .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.SelectContentControlsByTitle("Link")(1).Range, _
    Address:="Hyperlink Address", SubAddress:="", ScreenTip:="Some Tip", _
    TextToDisplay:="Display Text", Target:=""
End With
```

For further details, see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.hyperlinks.add

Comment: Thank you macropod, and to the others, when I try the above which has gotten me closer than anything else I receive a new message "out of memory". Must be me doing somthing wrong as I'm totally new at this but I though adding text to a content control as a hyperlink would be simple but I bet I'm close!

Comment: That is not likely to be caused by the code, but by what you're passing to it as the hyperlink or by something faulty with your system and/or Office installation.