# Hyperlinks in content controls in headers and footers in VBA for MS-Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

The solution to [Add hyperlink into Word Content Control with VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26538906/add-hyperlink-into-word-content-control-with-vba) describe how you can add hyperlinks to content controls.  This doesn't seem to work for **headers** and **footers**.  Do you know of a way to add hyperlinks to content controls in **headers** and **footers**?

Comment: In what way doesn’t it work?

Comment: Also, in Word documents, as such, hyperlinks are not very useful in headers or footers.